# R case_when with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the function i am trying to run.

```
fx_SegmentCustomer <- function(Rx,Fx,Mx){
  case_when(between(Rx,4,5) , between(Fx,4,5), between(Mx,4,5) ~ "xyz",
            TRUE ~ NA_character_)
}
```

`fx_SegmentCustomer(5,4,5)`

Getting the following error:

> Blockquote
>
> Error: Case 1 (`between(Rx, 4, 5)`) must be a two-sided formula, not a
>   logical vector

i guess the logical vector needs to be cast into a boolean, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you meant was to separate the condition with AND (`&`).

```
library(dplyr)

fx_SegmentCustomer <- function(Rx,Fx,Mx){
  case_when(between(Rx,4,5) & between(Fx,4,5) & between(Mx,4,5) ~ "xyz",
            TRUE ~ NA_character_)
}

fx_SegmentCustomer(5,4,5)
#[1] "xyz"
```

Comment: actually it should be "and".

Comment: i was under the impression that comma can act as AND(&) in some places it does.